# Laravel: Get relationship in randomized order

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code where I get a random question with it's answers:

```
$q = Question::with('answers')
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->first();
```

I want to return the `answers` in random order.

My table structure is:

`questions`

`answers`

`answer_questions` - question_id, answer_id

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$q = Question::with(['answers' => function ($q) {
    $q->inRandomOrder();
}])->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

I called inRandomOrder on the answers relationship (so that answers will be randomly ordered) as well as question, so this query will return 1 random question with all of it's answers randomly orderer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$question= Question::inRandomOrder()->first();
$randomAnswer= $question->answers()->random();
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add `get()`: `Question::inRandomOrder()->first()->answers()->get()->random()`